# process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to do FB authentication in my web page in `node js` local host everything working fine but when i Deploy in `AWS EC2` error occurred. I used `mongodb` as database.

node.js 201 throw e:// process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick

```
Type error: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.inherits (util.js:512:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs-stream/download.js:46:6)
```

Comment: Is there any version miss match between your local machine and your server?

Comment: In Server the node version is v0.6.8 and in Local windows machine v4.4.7 .